# Google Analytics API creating custom tabs with custom data

Tags: php, google-analytics

Is there any API, which creates custom tabs in Google Analytics API.
I wanted to push my custom data and show it in the seperate tab with my custom reporting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ganesh**, you could use [Custom Reports](https://www.google.com/analytics/web/?hl=en#croverview/cr-overview/) for this. However, you would need to setup the reports by yourself first using GA web interface (which is pretty clean and easy to learn).

**Just pick dimensions and metrics you want, apply any include/exclude filters and you are done!**